# When does Pralay (Catastrophe) occurs ? Who survives after Pralay ? What are the details about Pralay?

Tags: pralaya

When does Pralay (Catastrophe) occurs ? Who survives after Pralay ? What are the details about Pralay ?

Does Pralay occurs at the end of each Yuga ?

Comment: There are cosmic rules.
1) If majority wants  to go back to being animals then a pralaya  ensues…await an asteroid. 
2) Paramatma is in you… Not enough realizers of  it  left…over thousands of years and still resort to evil and violent ways then a dissolution is in order. Pralaya ensues….  Nature knows how to regrow a plant. She was the only witness of Pralaya … Moola Prakriti is the only Maha Pralaya Sakshin & she can speak only through Silence.. very few entities are left after pralaya to recount…How is humanity helping her to steer away from such outcome is the real test 